Issues with generateMetadata for Dynamic Social Media Sharing Tags in Next.js 13
I am encountering an issue with setting up dynamic metadata for social media sharing, specifically for WhatsApp, using Next.js 13's generateMetadata function. The metadata isn't being reflected when I share my product link. This is what I aim to achieve:
enter image description here
Here's my current setup as per the Next.js 13 documentation:
In app/[product]/page.jsx

import React from "react";
import Footer from "@/components/footer/Footer";
import InformacionDelProducto from "@/components/productos/InformacionDelProducto";
import { obtenerProductoTitulo } from '@/utils/loaders';

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const { producto } = params || {};
  const { data, error: fetchError } = await obtenerProductoTitulo(producto);

  if (fetchError || !data) {
    console.error('Error fetching product:', fetchError);
    return {
      title: `${producto} - Product not found`,
    };
  }

  return {
    title: data.producto_titulo,
    description: data.producto_descripcion,
  };
};
// ...rest of the component


I've followed the generateMetadata usage instructions as shown in the Next.js 13 documentation example:
// From Next.js 13 documentation
export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }: Props, parent: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {
  // ...
}

However, when I share the product link, the dynamic metadata such as title or description are not showing up in WhatsApp. I've attached a screenshot from a sharing attempt where the issue can be seen.
Previously, exporting a static metadata object from layout.js or page.js worked, but I need the metadata to be dynamic and fetched from the database.
Could anyone assist me in understanding what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing for dynamic metadata to work correctly for social media sharing?
Attached are the screenshot and relevant source code.
Thanks for the help!

What I've tried:

I followed the new Next.js 13 generateMetadata function pattern to generate dynamic metadata based on the product information fetched from the database.

I expected the dynamic metadata (specifically the title and description of the product) to be visible when sharing the product link on platforms like WhatsApp.


What I was expecting:
When sharing the product link on social media, I expected the link preview to dynamically show the product's title and description as set by the generateMetadata function, ensuring that each product shared would have unique and relevant metadata for users to see in the preview before clicking the link.
What actually happened:
Despite setting up the generateMetadata function correctly (to my knowledge), when I share the product link, the metadata isn't applied to the link preview. Instead, the preview lacks the product's title and description or shows default information, not the specific data fetched for that product.
Thanks for the help!
